# Karate mock - how to match against request body content

Tags: mocking, karate

With Karate, I'm trying to work out how to return different mock responses based on the content of the request body.

I've got

```
Feature: ...
Scenario: pathMatches('/users/login') && methodIs('post') && request == {"username": "gooduser", "password": "goodpassword"}
  * def responseStatus = 200
  * def response = {"status: login ok"}
Scenario: pathMatches('/users/login') && methodIs('post') && request == {"username": "baduser", "password": "badpassword"}
  * def responseStatus = 401
  * def response = {"status: login not ok"}
Scenario:
  * print request
  * print requestHeaders
```

When I send a request with either the "gooduser" or "baduser" details, they're falling through to the default scenario. This prints the request, which looks like I'd expect.

For example, if I run

```
curl -X POST -d '{"username":"baduser","password":"badpassword"}' http://localhost:8999/users/login
```

I can see in the Karate logs that the first 2 scenarios are being skipped and the match is on (empty). However, the logs are also printing out the request body which looks correct, so I'm surprised the 2nd scenario isn't matching the request I'm sending.

Also, if I remove the '&& request = {...}' clause from the scenario, the match works fine.

Feels like I'm missing something obvious - can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `==` sign won't work for complex objects (in any language), which is why the [`match`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#match) syntax of Karate is such a big deal. Keep in mind that the `Scenario` expression is evaluated as pure JavaScript.

EDIT: for you the simplest option, is to just use the `request` object directly. Since it is JSON in your case, a simple JS expression like `request.username == 'gooduser'` will work !

For those who use XML, there are some Karate functions that will do what you need. [`bodyPath()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#bodypath) is what will also work for you. And it is better to make the decision based on one or two values in the payload, not the whole thing, and this is what *real* servers do anyways:

```
Scenario: pathMatches('/users/login') && methodIs('post') && bodyPath('$.username') == 'gooduser'
```

You can use [`karate.match(request, json)`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-match) also, but it won't be as elegant.

And as I initially mentioned in the comment, you could move the logic of deciding what to respond with into the body of the `Scenario`, something like this:

```
* def response = request.username == 'gooduser' ? read('good.json') : read('bad.json')
```

Comment: @monch1962 you are welcome ! I forgot to mention that sometimes, using an `if` condition once you are *within* the `Scenario` may be the simplest option ! since you have access to `request.username` for example

Comment: By trial-and-error I found that `&& request.username == 'gooduser'` also works in the Scenario line

Comment: @monch1962 and yes I should have recommended that in the first place, let me edit my answer, thanks !